# Toggle span text with i tag

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

How can i make my code above change the span text without removing the 'i' tag?

```
function toggle(e) {
 let txt = e.innerText;
 e.innerText = txt == 'Modo escuro' ? 'Modo claro' : 'Modo escuro';
}
```

```
                        <a onclick="toggle(this)" id="theme-toggle" href="#" class="nav__link" >
                            <i class='bx bx-bulb nav__icon' ></i>
                            <span class="nav__name">Modo escuro</span>
                        </a>
```

live demo here: https://pauletatv.netlify.app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Includes it

Just add your tags into your `.innerHTML` element.

```js
let modo = 0;

function toggle(e) {
  if (modo == 0) {
    e.innerHTML = "<i class='bx bx-bulb nav__icon' ></i><span class='nav__name'>Modo claro</span>";
    modo = 1;
  } else {
    e.innerHTML = "<i class='bx bx-bulb nav__icon' ></i><span class='nav__name'>Modo escuro</span>";
    modo = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="toggle(this)" id="theme-toggle" href="#" class="nav__link" >Click</a>
```

---

### In alternative

You can check user theme preference cookies, in this way:

```js
let modo = 0;

if (document.cookie.indexOf("theme=1") !== -1) {
  modo = 1;
}

function toggle(e) {
  if (modo == 0) {
    e.innerHTML = "<i class='bx bx-bulb nav__icon' ></i><span class='nav__name'>Modo claro</span>";
    modo = 1;
  } else {
    e.innerHTML = "<i class='bx bx-bulb nav__icon' ></i><span class='nav__name'>Modo escuro</span>";
    modo = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="toggle(this)" id="theme-toggle" href="#" class="nav__link" >Click</a>
```

Comment: Exactly! and what if i want to change another span elements?

Comment: Same, you can do whatever you want if you'll put everything in `.innerHTML`